# Pass an asp.net variable to javascript failed

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am going to pass an variable from asp.net server to the javascript but I got an exception.

> The name 'serializer' does not exist in the current context
>   In my Admin.aspx.cs

```
 protected static string urlEdit;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // blah blah...
        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    }
```

Then in the markup code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function Edit_Click() {
                var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();


                options.url = <%= serializer.Serialize(urlEdit) %>;

                              };
```

Comment: Your variable has to be accessible to the generated page markup, so declare it outside of Page_Load. I presented a solution which could be considered a better practice with hidden fields.

Comment: @ericosg hidden fields are not good practice...

Comment: @user1090190 why aren't hidden fields good practice?

Comment: @jrummell Why would you want to send extra data when you don't need to?

Comment: It depends on the context of the problem. If you need that extra data, then it wouldn't be extra.

Comment: @jrummell perhaps I should rephrase. Why, when you're trying to pass a variable from server side to client side, would you want to use a hidden input field that needs to be input into the DOM, is extra data to be sent from server to client and is now clustered in your post data? If they didn't have their uses they wouldn't be there, but passing a server side variable to javascript via a hidden a hidden input is asinine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serializer` only exists in `Page_Load`. Instead of accessing serializer from your markup, why not create public method or property that returns the serialized value instead?

```
protected static string urlEdit;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // blah blah...
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
}

public string GetSerializedUrl()
{
    return serializer.Serialize(urlEdit);
}
```

Then call this method in your markup:

```
options.url = "<%= GetSerializedUrl() %>";
```

**Update**

Actually ... you don't need to serialize a string to use it javascript. So your code could be simplified to the following:

```
protected static string urlEdit = "www.example.com";
```

And the simplified markup:

```
options.url = "<%= urlEdit  %>";
```

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping it in quotes so the javascript will see it as a string...

```
options.url = '<%= serializer.Serialize(urlEdit) %>';
```

---

your code would render...

```
options.url = site.com/url;//invalid javascript
```

where as mine would render...

```
options.url = 'site.com/url';//valid javascript
```

Comment: well it is a step in the right direction. Perhaps you have escape characters in your string? like `\\` (backslash) for example? Also, do you have any javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

`serializer` only exists within the Page_Load function. For your inline code to recognize it, it needs to be declared in the classes namespace.

```
protected static string urlEdit;
protected var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

musefan is also right that options.url needs to be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: That's not global, its a public field on a class.

Answer (score 0):

Normally instead to serialize the variable inject the value into the javaScript with this values

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "variable", "<script language=javascript> var variableUrl='" + urlEdit+"' </script>");
```

Notes that this block of code should be in the load method of your page

then in you script, you could use the variable like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Edit_Click() {
            var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();


            options.url = variableUrl;

                          };
```

Answer (score -2):

Personally, I find it easy to make use of hidden fields to do the job.

i.e.

Markup (.aspx)

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenRequest" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Code behind (.aspx.cs)

```
hiddenRequest.value = "Test!";
string test = (string)hiddenRequest.value;
```

Javascript with jQuery (for easy selection) (.js)

```
$('#hiddenRequest').val('Test!');
var test = $('#hiddenRequest').val();
```

Comment: perhaps i should have elaborated on why I believe it's a better practice before just stating my personal choice.